# Custom UITextField not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to create a custom `UITextField` that shows a date picker instead of a keyboard.  I already change the textfields in my storyboard to use DateTextField custom class, however, still the keyboard is being shown instead of the date picker.  Note that the textfields are inside a `UITableviewCell`.
Also, i am not sure if this is the correct way of creating the toolbar:

```
self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.superview.bounds.size.width, 44)];



@interface DateTextField : UITextField

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIToolbar *datePickerToolbar;

@end


@implementation DateTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.superview.bounds.size.width, 44)];
        [self.datePickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
        UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setDatePickerValue:)];
        [self.datePickerToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:extraSpace, doneButton, nil]];
        self.inputView = self.datePicker;
        self.inputAccessoryView = self.datePickerToolbar;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Have you verified that this `initWithFrame:` method is ever called?

Comment: hmmm, oh, it's not being called... i thought just setting the textfield to my custom textfield will do the initialization... sorry it's my first time to customize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the textfields in storyboard/xib the `init` method will not be called.

Try with `awakeFromNib`. Move all the code in the `init` method to `awakeFromNib`

```
    - (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

   self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    self.datePickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.superview.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [self.datePickerToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(setDatePickerValue:)];
    [self.datePickerToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:extraSpace, doneButton, nil]];
    self.inputView = self.datePicker;
    self.inputAccessoryView = self.datePickerToolbar;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `UITextField`, why don't you use a `UIButton`. It saves a whole lot of time in the future. In this case, the `UIButton` acts like a UILabel with a tap gesture recognizer.

However, if you need to use `UITextField`, do this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:yourTextField])
    {

        // Present the picker here first 
           ...

        // And then...    
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Oh and also, do not initialize any `UIView` subclass properties inside any `-initWith...` methods. That will trigger a mismatched view lifecycle. Initialize/access these properties inside `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: UIButton is not a good idea when the UITextField have the inputView property. Also viewDidLoad is available only in UIViewController.